# How to create PKCS#11 keystore

Tags: jvm, pkcs#11, hsm, opendj

I have an activated partition on Luna HSM and configured the HSM. 
My server can talk to HSM, cert are exchanged and vtl verify works.
Installed OpenDJ(Directory server, or Could be any application) then I wanted to use an existing certificate on PCKS11 token.

Could anyone please provide instructions to use the cert from HSM?

Error I get- 
 Could not access the PKCS#11 keystore. Check that the JVM security settings
have been configured to use a PKCS#11 keystore and that a valid password has
been provided if needed. Error details: PKCS11 not found

Comment: Could you provide minimal working code depicting your problem.

Comment: How about you just read the OpenDJ documentation that explains how to use HSM and certificates with the OpenDJ product ?

Comment: And https://marginnotes2.wordpress.com/2017/08/14/storing-opendj-server-keys-on-the-nitrokey-hsm may have some answers to your question, althought this is using a different HSM.